# Kohana ORM structure and alias misfits

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Tables are

```
buildings (id)
contacts(id)
building_administrators (id, building_id, contact_id)
```

Model is

```
Model_Building {
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'administrators' => array(
            'model' => 'Contact',
            'through' => 'building_administrators',
            'foreign_key' => 'building_id'          
        ),
    );
}
```

After quering `$building->administrators->find_all();` i get error: 
`Unknown column 'building_administrators.administrator_id' in 'on clause' [ SELECT ..`

Is there any way to solve this?

I can solve it by renaming administrator alias to contacts, but then i have to query with `$building->contacts->find_all()` and that's not good (maybe i have a administrations and brokers for example).

I can also rename contact_id to administrator_id in database table, but then DB structure is wrong - i don't have administrators table.

Comment: Try adding `'far_key' => 'contact_id',` to the array. Some background: `foreign_key` is the keyname `$this` object has in the relationship description, `far_key` is the keyname the external object has in the relationship.

Comment: Perfect! Now .. how can i give you my points?

Comment: I have put my comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `'far_key' => 'contact_id'`, to the array.

Some background: `foreign_key` is the keyname `$this` object has in the relationship description, `far_key` is the keyname the external object has in the relationship

EDIT: Just wanted to add that Kohana, if the required keys are missing, guesses her own keynames based on the alias name ( http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM#get )